# Как масштабировать фигуру по глобальной оси ОХ при повороте фигуры?

Tags: матрицы, графика, геометрия, 2d

У меня есть координаты некоторой фигуры, такие что центр фигуры это начало координат. Есть матрицы масштабирования, поворота, сдвига, которые умножаются на координаты фигуры (последовательность: масштабирование, поворот, сдвиг) чтобы получить координаты в глобальной системе отсчета. Масштабирование всегда должно быть по оси ОХ, но если я поверну фигуру например на 90 градусов и буду масштабировать то фигура будет вытягиваться по вертикали, а не по горизонтали, т.к.  умножение матрицы масштабирования идёт перед поворотом, так вот: как масштабировать относительно глобальной оси ОХ несмотря на поворот фигуры?

Comment: А почему нужно масштабировать именно перед поворотом? Такое ограничение в задании?

Comment: Просто если да, то классическое решение этой проблемы - домножить матрицу масштабирования слева на матрицу поворота на угол `-a`, а справа - на матрицу поворота с углом `+a`, где `a` - это угол между глобальной OX и осью самой фигуры, вдоль которой хотите её вытягивать.

Comment: При этом если фигуру и дальше предполагается вращать как угодно, нужно хранить историю этих вращений в этой переменной `a`, значение которой будет влиять на матрицу масштабирования. Тогда вытягивание всегда будет таким, как надо не зависимо от поворота.

Comment: @Zealint это самый оптимальный порядок, при другом возможны конфликты, но я пробовал менять местами поворот и масштабирование, результат очень далеко от желаемого)

Comment: @Zealint Возможно ли проделать все тоже самое, но масштабирование относительно произвольно заданной точки?

Comment: можно всё проделать что угодно, что умещается в матрицу 3x3. Если точно поставите задачу, вам помогут найти точное решение, а так, если честно, я не понял что такое масштабирование относительно точки. Вероятнее всего, вы имели в виду масштабирование вдоль некоторого заданного вектора? Да, можно, для этого нужно найти матрицу преобразования, которая располагает вашу фигуру вдоль этого вектора, а затем обратную к ней. Первую умножить слева на масштабирование, а вторую - справа. Но это если я верно вас понял.

Comment: @Zealint в качестве частного случая масштабирования относительно заданной точки можно рассматривать зеркальное отражение фигуры относительно заданной точки

Comment: ну так ведь отражение относительно точки предполагает направление этого отражения, верно? Там бесконечно много направлений, как выбрать желаемое?

Comment: @Zealint в моем случае это горизонтальная прямая на уровне выбранной точки

Comment: есть хорошая книга Д. Роджерса "Алгоритмические основы машинной графики", 17 лет назад я прочитал её и всё что знаю - знаю оттуда. А именно, в вашем случае помимо поворота нужно ещё сделать смещение. То есть делаете матрицу смещения `T_V`на вектор `V`, и обратную к ней матрицу: `T_{-V}`. Далее такой пирог: `T_{-V} * R_{-a} * S * R_a * T_V`. Ничего сложного. Дальнейшие вопросы прошу задавать указанной книге, либо в моём профиле есть ссылка для индивидуальных консультаций.

Comment: @Zealint спасибо за книгу, но матрица смещения съедается и отражение происходит относительно центра фигуры

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Раз мой комментарий подошёл автору, оформлю ответ полностью для других.

Чтобы масштабировать фигуру вдоль оси `OX` так, как будто мы не делали её вращения, нужно в саму процедуру масштабирования заложить вращение в обратную строну, а потом снова в исходное состояние. Пусть `S` - матрица масштабирования, а `R_a` - матрица поворота на угол `a`, который является углом между осью `OX` и осью фигуры, вдоль которой требуется растяжение (сжатие). Тогда нужно домножить матрицу масштабирования слева и справа следующим образом:

```
S_a = R_{-a} * S * R_a
```

Теперь новая матрица масштабирования `S_a` как бы возвращает нашу фигуру в состояния до вращения, масштабирует, и возвращает обратно как было.

Для того чтобы впоследствии делать другие повороты, нужно суммировать все углы в эту же переменную `a`, и масштабировать той же матрицей `S_a`.